# Pushing project from default branch to other branch

Tags: github

i have a repository contain 3 branches (main , branch1, branch2).

main is the default branch.

in main i have a project, in branch 1 and 2 i have a empty nothing.

I want to copy project in main to the 2 other branches.

how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout main
git checkout branch1 .  #copies the contents of main into working directory
git commit -am "Making branch1 match main"
```

do the same with branch2